# What does "academic" mean in "academic political philosophy"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Some meanings provided for "academic" on Merriam-Webster are:

1. Of, relating to, or associated with an academy or school especially of higher learning 
   "the academic curriculum"
   "academic courses"
2. THEORETICAL, SPECULATIVE
   "a purely academic question"
3. Having no practical or useful significance

Each of these meanings of "academic" gives a different meaning to "academic political philosophy". Which one will be it? Please, help me out. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: I could jokingly suggest (3) but I am pretty sure you want (1).

Comment: It would be better if you could provide the sentence where you read this.

Comment: It could actually be any of them.  If it's mentioned on a university website or in someone's CV, it's (1).  If it's mentioned dismissively in a politician's speech and contrasted with real-world practical politics, it's (2) or (3).

Comment: Thank you so much guys.